# Is there support for AnimatorSet API lower than 23?

Tags: android, nineoldandroids

I have been using [NineOldAndroids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids) for animation which now deprecated. Today, I found there is this ViewCompat just like ViewHelper from NineOldAndroids. So, is there any AnimatorSet compat that can be used for lower API, like API 8?

Comment: level 8? no, but level 11, yes

Comment: @pskink. Thanks for this.